# Filter a DataGridView with Textbox in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, search, filter

Im trying to create a software that contains information manually added by user inside `datagridtextcell`.
The purpose of it is to filter the `DataGridView` afterwards with a `Textbox`. The software should filter out the text information and display the rows, that contain the text information related to the `TextBox`.

I don't use MySQL or anything that is Database related.

I use a `Textbox` with name `textBox1` and using its `TextChanged` event.
The user is writing data inside 3 tables called indexView, kategorieView and inhaltView inside `dataGridView1`.

What happens when I enter data inside the `TextBox` it just resets the `DataGridView` to zero content.

Im a beginner in Visual Studio and in C#. I have basic knowledge in C.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn iView;
    private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn kView;
    private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn cView;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

         BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
         bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;

         bs.Filter = "indexView like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
         bs.Filter = "kategorieView like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
         bs.Filter = "inhaltView like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";

         dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        indexView = iView;
        kategorieView = kView;
        inhaltView = cView;
    }

}
```

Comment: try something like this, insted of using Filter multyple times       (DataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("indexView LIKE '{0}%' OR kategorieView LIKE '% {1}%' OR inhaltView LIKE '% {2}%'", textBox1.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox1.Text);

Comment: what is your initial data source? where and how do you store the original data?

Comment: could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59282097/edit) your post and add the code? it is unreadable in a comment

Comment: Hello @Mong Zhu, post is updated. Hello Democrats thank you for the links - Im still reading and trying to figure out where to implement thr removefilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason may be that the data source of the DataGridView is always `null`. You can try to define a `DataTable` to store the data, and then use it as the `DataSource` of `BindingSource`.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Define a datatable
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("tablename");
    DataRow dr;
    dt.Columns.Add("iView", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("kView", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("cView", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; i++)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            dr[j] = this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    // Filter
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dt;
    bs.Filter = "iView like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
    bs.Filter = "kView like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
    bs.Filter = "cView like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
    // Reset the datagridview content
    dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}
```

The result,

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr. Wang. This is helping me alot. Now I can work on keeping/restoring the original data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter?view=netframework-4.8) you should call [RemoveFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.removefilter?view=netframework-4.8) first.

*...Additionally, the Filter value will persist when the data source changes. To stop filtering the DataSource, call the RemoveFilter method.*

Answer (score 0):

I did't made up a solution that satesfy me.

So swiped the whole project to a local database. There where alot of tutorials online with many good solutions.

I learned some important stuff and I appreciate the help of everyone.

-TOPIC CLOSED-